# How to write unit tests for Spring Kafka transactions with MockProducer

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, apache-kafka, mockito, spring-kafka

I have the following producer-only transactions setup with Spring transaction support.

```
@Transactional
public boolean sendData(String topic, Data data) {
    //returns new ProducerRecord<>(topic, data)
    final ProducerRecord<String, Data> producerRecord = createRecord(topic, data);

    try {
        kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    catch (ExecutionException e) {
        log.error(data, e);
        return false;
    }
    catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) {
        log.error(data, e);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx- #producer property
```

Is there a way to write the unit tests to cover successful commit and failure rollback scenarios using MockProducer?

**Edit**

I am planning to follow this testing approach for commit and rollback.

```
@Test
void testValueWhenSendOnTransactionalCommit() {
    MockProducer<String, Data> mockProducer = new MockProducer<>(true, new StringSerializer(), new JsonSerializer<>())

    var kafkaTemplate = //How to proceed with KafkaTemplate 
    //initTransaction() and beginTransaction()
    var record = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord); //Mock producerRecord

    assertTrue(mockProducer.history().isEmpty());
    //commitTransaction()
    assertTrue(mockProducer.history().size() == 1);
}
```

Comment: Please check on the below Kafka reference for  Unit tests written for Producer transaction  behaviours as well https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/MockProducerTest.java

Answer (score 0):

The `KafkaTemplate` and `KafkaTransactionManager` for that `@Transactional` must be configured for the same `ProducerFactory`. Yes, you can implement one for the mentioned `MockProducer`. Then you perform your unit tests respectively and using that `MockProducer` API. Please, share with us what have you tried so far.

Comment: See the unit testing approach that I recently added.

Comment: Your test is not related to the code you've shown before. If you talk about testing of that transactional method, then you have to call exactly that method from your unit test. Yes, since you want to deal with a `MockProducer` you need to figure out how to inject a custom `ProducerFactory` for this `MockProducer` into your application context, so a `KafkaTemplate` and `KafkaTransactionManager` are going to deal with exactly your `MockProducer`. Perhaps `@MockBean` could be the way if you really use Spring Boot.

Comment: See also this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2673